# Xcode 10 beta uses tons of storage

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios12

I am trying to use Xcode 10 beta(5) to compile the project from work to get it ready for iOS 12. However, as soon as I started Xcode 10 (since beta 1), it will start eating the storage on my computer:

After the first compile, it will occupy 8GB of extra storage; then for each run, it will take about 0.5GB ~ 1GB more storage; even for the precompiling, it will use significantly more storage on my Mac.

Long story short, I have about 30GB free storage on my Mac. After several round of runs of the app, Xcode 10 beta will eventually kill my computer because it will take almost all of the storage (with only 60MB left).

I tried to clean the project folder and delete derived data, but it doesn't help. However, as soon as I restart my computer, all the space will be freed.

I wonder does anyone else has this issue? Is it a configuration issue on Xcode or it's an actual Xcode 10 bug? I don't know if it matters, but our project includes several frameworks targets and 1 app target to use those frameworks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue with deleting duplicated device support files. I am just using ios 12 device support for xcode 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can even check archives folder and delete it's entire content.

Basically what I do is clear up derive data, then clear archives (both folder lie in the same parent folder). You can delete unnecessary simulators as they also takes a lot of space as well as older device support files.

I use a software called daisey disk that graphically shows which folders in you mac in taking how much of storage and you can even navigate inside further and check the storage taken correspondingly by each folders

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of memory issue, don't download the simulators for Xcode 10. 
just work with iOS12 Simulator with Xcode 10.